# How to create a unique constraint on the date of a timestamp

Tags: database, postgresql

In postgresql (9.2), I have a table with:

```
  tservice         timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  patient_recid    integer NOT NULL
```

I wish to create a unique constraint on the *date* of tservice, something like:

```
  constraint service_unique UNIQUE (patient_recid, tservice::date)
```

which produces a syntax error at the date cast.

How is this best done in PostgreSQL?

TIA

Comment: You can't create a constraint on an expression. You need to use a unique *index*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strange, it seems that PostgreSQL allows only for columns in unique constraint, but expressions are not allowed here.

You can create an unique functional index (as a workaround), indexes on expressions are supported from version 9.1:

```
create unique index service_unique 
ON table_name(patient_recid, date_trunc('day',tservice));
```

Comment: it  doesn't  work on 9.6 version `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2: ...ty_id_desc_date UNIQUE ( date_trunc('day',pwk...`

Answer (score 7):

As stated before, `UNIQUE INDEX` works pretty well. 
For those who get the "functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE" error, you can fix the timezone in your index :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX service_unique ON table_name(patient_recid, date_trunc('day',tservice AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast tservice when creating the constraint.

If the contraint should apply to the tservice as type "date" you might as well create the tservice column as type "date" instead.

You can update the type of the column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN tservice TYPE date;
```

and then add the constraint like so:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD CONSTRAINT service_unique UNIQUE (patient_recid, tservice)
```